# How does one show that $\frac{x^2 + 1}{x+1}$ is $O(x)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, computational-complexity

I found [this pdf solution](http://courses.ics.hawaii.edu/ReviewICS141/morea/algorithms/GrowthFunctions-QA.pdf) to the problem (see bottom of page 2), but I don't understand their approach. I understand how they used algebra to rewrite the function in simpler terms, but I don't quite understand how to prove that:

$x - 1 + \frac{2}{x+1} \leq cx$ for $c = 1$ and $x > 1$

Here's what I did:

Let $x \geq 1$:

$x + 1 \geq 2$

$\frac{1}{x+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{2}{x+1} \leq 1 \leq x$

So I rewrote the inequality as:

$x - 1 + \frac{2}{x+1} \leq x + 0 + x $

The right side is term-for-term greater than or equal to the left side.

$x - 1 + \frac{2}{x+1} \leq 2x$, where the witness $c = 2$

Is my approach valid? How does the pdf approach work? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes. it is true. But to consider these, you can ignore constants and get the result in a faster mode. So, $\frac{x^2}{x} = O(x)$.

Comment: But that's not a rigorous mathematical proof, and I was asked to show that it's true. I know how the intuition works.

Comment: for $x>1$ we have that $2/(x+1)<1$. Thus we get the inequality $x-1+2/(x+1)<x$ for $x>1$.

Comment: Why write it it as $x+0+x$ shouldn't it be $x-1+x$?

Comment: Because $x + 0 + x \geq x - 1 + x \geq x - 1 + \frac{2}{x+1}$, so it's just easier to write it that way because it allows you to drop the constant $-1$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) \in O(g(x)) \iff \|f(x)\| < M \|g(x)\|$ for $x \to \infty$ Now $$ \frac{x^2 + 1}{x(x+1)} \to 1$$ hence ... $\frac{x^2 + 1}{x+1} < 2 x$ for $x$ large enough.

Suppose that there are infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{x_k^2+1}{x_k+1} \geq 2x_k$ hence $\frac{x_k^2 + 1}{x_k(x_k+1)} \geq 2$ which is a contradiction with the fact that $\frac{x_k^2 + 1}{x_k(x_k+1)} \to 1$

Comment: This shows that $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}\ll2x$, but it does not directly imply the inequality for all $x$.

Comment: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation says that it inequality must hold just for $x$ large enough, which happens with $2$ because the limit is $1$ right?

Comment: I didn't understand what you wrote beyond the first line :(

Comment: @CMarius Your last line explicitly says $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}<2x$$this doesn't hold for all $x$ and is very much different from saying $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=\mathcal O(x)$$if you want to state it in an inequality form, you must state for what values of $x$ it holds for or at least hint that it holds for sufficiently large $x$.  I digress, I'm being nitpicky, but for your updated answer, consider : $$x_k=\frac1{k+1}$$where the inequality fails.

Comment: Suppose that there are infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{x_k^2+1}{x_k+1} \geq 2x_k$ hence $\frac{x_k^2 + 1}{x_k(x_k+1)} \geq 2$ which is a contradiction with the fact that $\frac{x_k^2 + 1}{x_k(x_k+1)} \to 1$

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art ok I've modified my answer :)